# API endpoint as a django model

Tags: python, django

I want an API endpoint to be linked to a model that supports relationships.
For example, if I have an endpoint http://api-url/users which gives all users, I want to create a model 'Order' with a field 'user' which is a ForiegnKey to a User model linked to the API.

Comment: OK. So what's your question?

Comment: This might help: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: The API is separate with the Project. ie. the API with the endpoint "user" is a separate API and the project containing the "Orders" model is separate. then the "Order" model has a field "user" which should be a ForiegnKey to a "User" object from the other API.